# Unexpected token '?' using, Discord.js Slash Command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Note: This is all about slash commands, so please don't suggest questions that don't have anything to do with my problem.

I'm new to 13v of discord.js, and I'm trying to settle in with it, I followed the 13v DSJ guide but still failed to make a slash commands handler, when I try to register my commands I get this error with a long weird code, the code has some kind of meaning, but it's hard to understand as I'm not a really good developer, here is my error:

```
~/Test$ node deploy-commands.js
/home/runner/Test/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1
var Re=Object.create;var A=Object.defineProperty;var be=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor;var ye=Object.getOwnPropertyNames;var ve=Object.getPrototypeOf,we=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;var Ee=(r,e,t)=>e in r?A(r,e,{enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0,value:t}):r[e]=t;var te=r=>A(r,"__esModule",{value:!0});var Le=(r,e)=>()=>(e||r((e={exports:{}}).exports,e),e.exports),Se=(r,e)=>{for(var t in e)A(r,t,{get:e[t],enumerable:!0})},se=(r,e,t,s)=>{if(e&&typeof e=="object"||typeof e=="function")for(let i of ye(e))!we.call(r,i)&&(t||i!=="default")&&A(r,i,{get:()=>e[i],enumerable:!(s=be(e,i))||s.enumerable});return r},W=(r,e)=>se(te(A(r!=null?Re(ve(r)):{},"default",!e&&r&&r.__esModule?{get:()=>r.default,enumerable:!0}:{value:r,enumerable:!0})),r),xe=(r=>(e,t)=>r&&r.get(e)||(t=se(te({}),e,1),r&&r.set(e,t),t))(typeof WeakMap!="undefined"?new WeakMap:0);var l=(r,e,t)=>(Ee(r,typeof e!="symbol"?e+"":e,t),t),ie=(r,e,t)=>{if(!e.has(r))throw TypeError("Cannot "+t)};var u=(r,e,t)=>(ie(r,e,"read from private field"),t?t.call(r):e.get(r)),E=(r,e,t)=>{if(e.has(r))throw TypeError("Cannot add the same private member more than once");e instanceof WeakSet?e.add(r):e.set(r,t)},g=(r,e,t,s)=>(ie(r,e,"write to private field"),s?s.call(r,t):e.set(r,t),t);var re=Le((Oe,De)=>{De.exports={name:"@discordjs/rest",version:"0.3.0",description:"The REST API for discord.js",scripts:{build:"tsup && tsc --emitDeclarationOnly --incremental",test:"jest --pass-with-no-tests --collect-coverage",lint:"prettier --check . && eslint src __tests__ --ext mjs,js,ts",format:"prettier --write . && eslint src __tests__ --ext mjs,js,ts --fix",docs:"typedoc --json docs/typedoc-out.json src/index.ts && node scripts/docs.mjs",prepublishOnly:"yarn build && yarn lint && yarn test",changelog:"git cliff --prepend ./CHANGELOG.md -u -c ./cliff.toml -r ../../ --include-path 'packages/rest/*'"},main:"./dist/index.js",module:"./dist/index.mjs",typings:"./dist/index.d.ts",exports:{import:"./dist/index.mjs",require:"./dist/index.js"},directories:{lib:"src",test:"__tests__"},files:["dist"],contributors:["Crawl <icrawltogo@gmail.com>","Amish Shah <amishshah.2k@gmail.com>","SpaceEEC <spaceeec@yahoo.com>","Vlad Frangu <kingdgrizzle@gmail.com>","Antonio Roman <kyradiscord@gmail.com>"],license:"Apache-2.0",keywords:["discord","api","rest","discordapp","discordjs"],repository:{type:"git",url:"git+https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js.git"},bugs:{url:"https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues"},homepage:"https://discord.js.org",dependencies:{"@discordjs/collection":"^0.4.0","@sapphire/async-queue":"^1.1.9","@sapphire/snowflake":"^3.0.1","discord-api-types":"^0.26.1","form-data":"^4.0.0","node-fetch":"^2.6.5",tslib:"^2.3.1"},devDependencies:{"@babel/core":"^7.16.12","@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators":"^7.16.7","@babel/preset-env":"^7.16.11","@babel/preset-typescript":"^7.16.7","@discordjs/ts-docgen":"^0.3.4","@types/jest":"^27.4.0","@types/node-fetch":"^2.5.10","@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin":"^5.10.0","@typescript-eslint/parser":"^5.10.0","babel-plugin-const-enum":"^1.2.0","babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata":"^0.3.2",eslint:"^8.7.0","eslint-config-marine":"^9.3.2","eslint-config-prettier":"^8.3.0","eslint-plugin-prettier":"^4.0.0",jest:"^27.4.7",nock:"^13.2.2",prettier:"^2.5.1",tsup:"^5.11.11",typedoc:"^0.22.11",typescript:"^4.5.5"},engines:{node:">=16.9.0"},publishConfig:{access:"public"}}});var $e={};Se($e,{ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:()=>F,ALLOWED_SIZES:()=>P,ALLOWED_STICKER_EXTENSIONS:()=>G,CDN:()=>U,DefaultRestOptions:()=>L,DefaultUserAgent:()=>C,DiscordAPIError:()=>S,HTTPError:()=>_,REST:()=>de,RESTEvents:()=>j,RateLimitError:()=>D,RequestManager:()=>K,RequestMethod:()=>N});var ne=require("discord-api-types/v9"),ae=re(),C=`DiscordBot (${ae.homepage}, ${ae.version})`,L={agent:{},api:"https://discord.com/api",cdn:"https://cdn.discordapp.com",headers:{},invalidRequestWarningInterval:0,globalRequestsPerSecond:50,offset:50,rejectOnRateLimit:null,retries:3,timeout:15e3,userAgentAppendix:`Node.js ${process.version}`,version:ne.APIVersion,hashSweepInterval:144e5,hashLifetime:864e5,handlerSweepInterval:36e5},j=(m=>(m.Debug="restDebug",m.InvalidRequestWarning="invalidRequestWarning",m.RateLimited="rateLimited",m.Request="request",m.Response="response",m.HashSweep="hashSweep",m.HandlerSweep="handlerSweep",m))(j||{}),F=["webp","png","jpg","jpeg","gif"],G=["png","json"],P=[16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096];var U=class{constructor(e=L.cdn){this.base=e}appAsset(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/app-assets/${e}/${t}`,s)}appIcon(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/app-icons/${e}/${t}`,s)}avatar(e,t,s){return this.dynamicMakeURL(`/avatars/${e}/${t}`,t,s)}banner(e,t,s){return this.dynamicMakeURL(`/banners/${e}/${t}`,t,s)}channelIcon(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/channel-icons/${e}/${t}`,s)}defaultAvatar(e){return this.makeURL(`/embed/avatars/${e}`)}discoverySplash(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/discovery-splashes/${e}/${t}`,s)}emoji(e,t){return this.makeURL(`/emojis/${e}`,{extension:t})}guildMemberAvatar(e,t,s,i){return this.dynamicMakeURL(`/guilds/${e}/users/${t}/avatars/${s}`,s,i)}icon(e,t,s){return this.dynamicMakeURL(`/icons/${e}/${t}`,t,s)}roleIcon(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/role-icons/${e}/${t}`,s)}splash(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/splashes/${e}/${t}`,s)}sticker(e,t){return this.makeURL(`/stickers/${e}`,{allowedExtensions:G,extension:t??"png"})}stickerPackBanner(e,t){return this.makeURL(`/app-assets/710982414301790216/store/${e}`,t)}teamIcon(e,t,s){return this.makeURL(`/team-icons/${e}/${t}`,s)}dynamicMakeURL(e,t,{forceStatic:s=!1,...i}={}){return this.makeURL(e,!s&&t.startsWith("a_")?{...i,extension:"gif"}:i)}makeURL(e,{allowedExtensions:t=F,extension:s="webp",size:i}={}){if(s=String(s).toLowerCase(),!t.includes(s))throw new RangeError(`Invalid extension provided: ${s}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Test/deploy-commands.js:2:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

Here is my code from "deploy-commands.js":

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId), { body: commands })
    .then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
    .catch(console.error);
```

```
Info:
  Discord.js: "^13.6.0", 
  Node: "^16.13.2", 
  Host: "Replit", 
  run = "npm start", 
    start: "node ."
```

Comment: The only thing I can see that could be a potential issue is `t??"png"`. But Node version 14+ shouldn't have a problem with this.

Comment: So, anyway I can't fix it though?

Comment: Are you sure replit uses `"node ^16.13.2"`?

Comment: I used a code to overwrite their default node version which fixed the "node:events" error I had before

Comment: So yes but no, as I'm not sure if they support it